# How to make countdown timer 24h iOS with continue function after closing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, nsuserdefaults, countdown

Is there any solutions for timer to continue countdown after app was closed?

Comment: Store the end time in NSUserDefaults and just display how long is left

Answer (score 1):

We had such issue in one of the apps and the issue was when the app was going in the background mode and then suspended by iOS. The timer stops counting at that time. For that, there were two solutions:

1. *Client-Side*: Use combination of `CACurrentMediaTime()` and normal `[NSDate date]` to know how much time has left. This approach has a flaw in which the app gets suspended and also user changes the OS time.
2. *Server-Side*: This approach is to have a server to do the countdown and notify the device when it's done.